# Displaying json data to view as String or array

Tags: php, database, laravel

New to Laravel and feel that I'm missing something important here. I am uploading and saving multiple files to a folder and saving an array of the images names to the database(simple enough). Currently saving the images name in the `json_encode()` format so they are formatted like so`["kittyTest.jpeg","kitty_2.jpeg","kitty_3.jpeg"]`. So when I try and print them out to the view I get them in the json format and am trying to display them in an array formate or in some way that I can use the filename for the source image. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Form;
use DB;

class FormController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
{
    $images = DB::select('select * from forms');

    //dd(json_decode($images[0]->filename));

    return view('index', ['images'=> $images]);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'filename' => 'required',
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
        foreach ($request->file('filename') as $image) {
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

    $form = new Form();
    $form->filename = json_encode($data);
    $form->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Your images have been uploaded');
}
```

}

**View**

```
<body>
<div class="container">


<h3 class="jumbotron">Laravel Multiple File Upload</h3>

<p>Here are the images we have in the database</p>

<ul class="list-group">
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ $image->filename }}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="list-group">
@foreach ($images as $image)
    @php $image_array = json_decode($image->filename,true); @endphp
    @foreach ($image_array as $img)
     <li class="list-group-item">

        {{ $img }}
     </li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</ul>
try this and let me know
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to json_decode every image filenames and then use second foreach in your view file.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $images = DB::select('select * from forms');

    array_map(function($a) { 
        $a->filename = json_decode($a->filename); 
        return $a; 
    }, $images);

    return view('index', compact($images)); // you can use compact function here
}
```

**View**

```
<ul class="list-group">
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        @foreach ( $image->filename as $file)
        {{ $file }}
        @endforeach
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**Edit:** You can also try [cast to array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting), then you dont need to worry about mapping it in your controller file.